# Oracle subselect case

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery, case

So, there are 2 tables

1. Table1 (Contains all articles,center,date 00000)
2. Tabla2 (Contains articles handwritten (that are also in Table1),center, date)

We have a procedure that every day compares Table1 and Table2 articles and center, and if they match, an update changes th Table1 date for that article and center.

Now, we also want to add something, we want that in case center is ' ' (empty) on Tabla2, it updates every center that has that article in Table1.
Here is the OracleSQL:

```
               update Table1 r
               set date1= (SELECT max(date2) FROM Tabla2 t 
               where t.articulo = r.articulo
               and t.center = to_char(center) //It gets the center from a select behind
               and t.date2 >= to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')
               group by t.center);
```

We want both cases to work

1. If center has a real center like 20, it only updates center 20.
2. If center has a empty '' then it updates every center with that article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
UPDATE Table1 r
SET date1 = ( SELECT MAX(date2)
                       KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY t.center NULLS LAST)
              FROM   Tabla2 t 
              WHERE  t.articulo = r.articulo
              AND    (t.center = r.center OR t.center IS NULL)
              AND    t.date2 >= TRUNC(sysdate)
            );
```

*Note: `KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST...` is used to prefer dates from a row with a non-`NULL` center over rows with a `NULL` center.*

Which, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (articulo, center, date1) AS
SELECT 1, 1, CAST(NULL AS DATE) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 4, NULL FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE tabla2 (articulo, center, date2) AS
SELECT 1, 1,    DATE '2023-05-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2,    DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2,    DATE '2023-05-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3,    DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL, DATE '2023-05-19' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, NULL, DATE '2023-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, NULL, DATE '2023-05-19' FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the update `Table1` contains:

> | ARTICULO | CENTER | DATE1 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | 2023-05-19 00:00:00 |
> | 2 | 2 | 2023-05-19 00:00:00 |
> | 3 | 3 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 |
> | 4 | 4 | 2023-05-19 00:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a452bec3d7c502147d50f96fa925e399)*

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
and t.center = nvl(to_char(center),t.center)
```

If the center is populated, it will use that value. If center is null, the nvl will instead result in the value of t.center. Basically resulting in t.center=t.center (which again means always true).

Comment: `t.center = t.center` will never be true when `t.center` is `NULL` (and in Oracle `''` is identical to `NULL`).

Comment: `t.center` will always have a value according to the original text as `t.center` contains the article currently attached to a center in the `table1`. If the article is in `table1` then `t.center` is always populated. If not, the request to update all centers does not make sense.
However, in the unlikely case there is a chance that `t.center` is `null`, you can replace each `t.center` item in my answer with `nvl(t.center,-99)`. Then even null values for t.center will work.

Comment: No, the OP said " in case center is `''` (empty)" and, in Oracle, an empty string is stored as `NULL` and `NULL = NULL` is never true so you will never match an empty string [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a6c6286bf27152687edb0484d0d06cbf)